# Is changing my operating system and still keeping virtualbox possible?

Tags: operating-system, virtualbox

I want to change my operating system from Windows to Ubuntu.
But I don't want to lose my Virtualbox. Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Best,
Miriam

Answer (score 1):

You can export your VMs in the OVA/OVF format using VirtualBox (File->Export Appliance, File->Import Appliance). This way you can get a fairly portable VM and back it up on some external hard drive. Then when you replace your host operating system from Windows to Ubuntu, you can import the VMs from the OVA/OVF file back to your Ubuntu host.